# How to calculate the totals of a column if its date is between two dates?

Tags: date, filter, google-sheets, conditional-statements

**Problem:**

I'm keeping track of employee hours in a Google Sheets populated by a Google Form.  I'm already breaking out each person into their own tab by using a `query`, but now that I have each person in their own tab, I need a good way to get total hours by 2-week pay periods.

**Details:**

I have data like below in a Google Sheets.  Basically, date, name, and hours worked.  I have the data being populated from a Google Forms, so I can't change the date format unfortunately. The data covers a large span of time, but I want to be able to calculate totals based on 2-week pay periods.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried `query` (#ERROR):

```
=query(!A3:J, "Select DSUM('Hours') Where A > '3/12/2016'")
```

I've tried `SUMIF` (0):

```
=SUMIF(A3:A14, "> '3/16/2016'", C3:C15)
```

and I've tried `DSUM` (but don't fully understand it) (#ERROR):

```
=DSUM(!A3:J, "Hours", {"> [not sure what to put here]")
```

**Data:**

`Date        Name        Hours
3/1/2016    John Doe    9.5
3/4/2016    John Doe    3
3/5/2016    John Doe    6.5
3/9/2016    John Doe    8
...
4/28/2016   John Doe    7`

**Bonus:**

Beyond just "how to calculate with date condition", is there a way to set this up to be less manual?  So I don't have to copy the formula each pay period, change the dates...etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the single quotes around the dates. But you're very close.

You can use something like this:

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C8,A2:A8,CONCAT("<=",E2),A2:A8,CONCAT(">=",D2))
```

Column A has the dates.

Column C has your hours.

Column D has the beginning of the pay period.

Column E has the end of the pay period

This way you can just enter the period and drag(copy) the formula down.

[image]

Comment: It gives the error: "Wrong number of arguments to SUMIF.  Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 5 arguments".

Comment: Make sure to use SUMIFS with an S at the end